# How to define this recursive formula in MatLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix-valued function defined as R which depends on n and I want to define the following algorithm in MatLAB:
$A_{0}=I$ , $B_{0}=0$ , $A_{1}=I$ ,$B_{1}=I$
for $j=1:2m$
$A_{j}= R_{j}A_{j-1}+A_{j-2}$;$B_{j}= R_{j}B_{j-1}+B_{j-2};$
end
$K_{m}=A_{2m}B_{2m}$, I have the following code in MatLAB, it does not work because[image] of some mismatch assignments. I think I am making some mistakes in the array assignments. I'd appreciate any hints or comments. Thanks

Comment: For one thing, you haven't defined Rn and m.  Also you might use A(1,:,:) rather than A(1) etc, or use A{1} for a cell array.

Comment: @RobertIsrael,  Here I call the function Rn(m,n) which is defined and saved. The error is not related to Rn though. I got a mismatch dimension error in the assignment of A(1). I tried {} before and I got the same error.

Comment: Another problem is that Rn is called with two arguments in line 10 and only one in line 11.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, right, thank you. However, the debuger stops at the very first line where A(1) or A{1} is eye(2), it does not go any further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example with cell arrays.

[image]